# A problem where the minimum number of a specific type of operations is to be done.

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

[image]

Hello everybody! I saw [this problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1945734_a_problem_with_minimum_value_needed) by a user sparkle23 which I found too interesting not to share.

The answers given by the user sparkle23 are $8,7,11$.

Unfortunately, I could not solve the problem. The user hopeless404 suggested this:

> For any instruction $I$, the total amoebae increase by $I-1$.
>   In the case of $(a)$, you can write a Diophantine eq which is $$23+(7-1)a+(12-1)b+(16-1)c=114$$ where the letters correspond to how many times their instruction is given.

but that would take too much time to test all the possible cases..

I have no idea how to start this but I thought of a brute-force thing but you can never be sure to have found the minimum value given that the values of $N$ and other things are pretty big in the sub-parts. Probably we can develop a recurrence relation and I think we'll have to do that but how?
I probably think that the the solution given by hopeless404 should work..

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation using the equation $$(A-1)a+(B-1)b+(C-1)c=N-K$$ is reasonably easy if you use modular arithmetic.

**For example, question(b)**

$$6a+14b+15c=67$$

Modulo $3$ (it's a good idea to use divisors of the coefficients) the equation becomes $2b\equiv 1$ (mod $3$) i.e.  $b\equiv 2$ (mod $3$). The only possibility is $b=2$.

Then 
$6a+15c=39$ i.e. $2a+5c=13$ gives $a=4,c=1$.

Can you do the others now? Arguably the most involved is Question (c) where 
$$8a+11b+25c=138$$
For a solution with a small number of instructions, you can consider separately the cases

$c=0, b\equiv 6$ (mod $8$) i.e $b=6$

$c=1, b\equiv 3$ (mod $8$) i.e $b=3$

$c=2, b\equiv 0$ (mod $8$) i.e $b=0$ or $8$

etc.

Note that $c=2,b=8$ gives a solution with $N=10$.

Comment: Thank you S. Dolan! I forgot that I could do some modulo considerations! Can you please add some detail to the first equation i.e. could you please explain it a bit to me?

Comment: Yes. If we do $a$ of instruction $A$, $b$ of instruction $B$, ... then the number of Amoeba increase by $a(A-1)+b(B-1)+c(C-1)$. this has to equal $N-K$.

Comment: OK I am able to “absorb” it now. It will probably take me some time to get the modular arithmetic in the answer otherwise I think this question was pretty much manageable. Thank you!